# how to prevent super-class from calling overriden sub-class methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I just ran into this issue, and it has taken me by surprise.

super-class:

```
public class Foo {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Result = %s", calculate());
    }
    public double calculate(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

sub-class:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s", super.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public double calculate(){
        return 123.456;
    }
}
```

driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Bar().toString());
}
```

The output I desire in this scenario is `1`
The output I get is `123.456`

How do I prevent Foo's `toString()` from calling Bar's `calculate()` ?

Comment: You can either create an instance of `Foo` instead of `Bar`, or simply don't override `Foo#calculate`.

Comment: The code I am working on requires this structure as-per the specifications

Comment: Are you able to call `super.calculate()` inside `Bar#calculate`?

Comment: That would be too easy, I am actually required to call: super.toString() inside Bar.toString()

Comment: You should accept @user2357112's answer then, as that is probably the best way to go about handling this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to let subclasses override `calculate` at all, mark it `final`:

```
public final double calculate() {
    ...
}
```

If you want to let them override `calculate`, but you don't want to use the overrides in this particular location, put the implementation of `calculate` in a private method and use the private version:

```
public double calculate() {
    return _calculate();
}
private double _calculate() {
    return 1.0;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Result = %s", _calculate());
}
```

Comment: The problem I am having is the specifications for what i am writing requires it to override, otherwise I would just use a workaround like this.

Comment: Either you did not understand the specifications or the specifications are wrong.

Comment: Based on my professor's track record, the latter is most likely correct. I will defer to the obvious solution you propose and use this as reference if she tries to take off marks for it. 
Is there any literature I can look up which will definitively confirm this?

Comment: Due to the most-likely malformed specifications, I doubt there was ever any literature written on this specific case, and there probably never will be!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it directly - you have overridden `calculate()` and since you have a `Bar` object it will always be `Bar.calculate()` that is called when `calculate()` is used<sup>1</sup>. It would very confusing and hard to make reasonable OoO designs if it were any other way!

If you really want the behavior as described, the usual solution is simply to have `Foo.toString()` call a non-overridable (e.g., `private` or `final`) helper method that implements the logic that you have in `Foo.calculate()`. Then you can be assured that `toString()` always behaves in the same way, even when `Foo` is overridden<sup>2</sup>. Then, you can implement `Foo.calculate()` by calling this helper method, pleasing the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) gods.

Of course, you might ask yourself if there is something wrong with your class design. The change suggested above means you have the unusual situation where `Foo.calculate()` is being used for `toString()` calls even on `Bar` objects, but a *direct* call to `calculate()` will result in the `Bar` behavior. So your `toString()` output is going to be inconsistent with what anyone who calls `calculate()` will see. That's rarely what you want.

---

<sup>1</sup>With the exception that it is possible, *within `Bar`*, to explicitly call the superclass `calculate()` method using `super.calculate()`. That doesn't help you here, since what you want to do is, in the superclass, prevent the virtual call to `calculate()` from going anywhere else.

<sup>2</sup>Of course, if someone overrides `toString()` then all bets are off. You can always make it `final` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: yeah, and the problem with my teacher's specs is that it's explicitly stated to use this structure and override toString()
The comments below @user2357112 's answer have confirmed that her specs are what's actually malformed here.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual specs. Note that if you override `Bar.toString()` you can certainly implement it terms of `Foo.calculate()` by using `super().calculate()`. You can't nicely do it by calling `super.toString()` - but there are some very ugly ways. For example, you could somehow communicate to `Bar.calculate()` that `toString()` is the caller and in that case delegate to `Foo.calculate()` using `super` - e.g., using TLS, examining the stack, or setting a field in the object. That's all quite terrible though.... @AnthonyAudette

Comment: Any solution I use is bound to be ugly, i'm tempted to leave the logic error in as it stands since the specifications are the teacher's problem. 
For clarity i'll explain the (convoluted) structure she wants.

Abstract ProjectInvoice>Labour extends ProjectInvoice>LabourAndMaterials extends Labour>LabourAndMaterialsAndEquipment extends LabourAndMaterials.

ProjectInvoice contains the abstract method calculateCost()

Each subclass overrides calculate cost and adds the super-class's calculation to it's own.
Each overrides toString and appends the output with it's additional information

Comment: @AnthonyAudette: It doesn't sound like there's anything in there about requiring `toString` to call `calculate`.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry I ran out of characters. Each sub-class implementation of toString calls calculate() for the current total. 
So labor would be "Labor total: $"+calculate(), and LabourAndMaterials would be super.toString()+"\nTotal With Materials: $"+calculate()"
(I have trimmed irrelevant data from these outputs) This is explicitly stated in the specs, so I defer to your assertion that the specs themselves are malformed. It would be far from the only problem with this teacher's assignments.

Comment: @AnthonyAudette You should post the specification in the question rather than having us guess at it (or hope that future readers dig into the comments here). My best guess is that you have misinterpreted the specification and asked a follow-on question based on that misinterpretation.

Comment: @AnthonyAudette - just post it in the question, where you have unlimited characters.

Comment: @BeeOnRope There isn't much need for future readers to dig into the comments, the answers here are sufficient and explain everything that's relevant. 
My clarification on the specifications are to explain how I came to this issue, and to clarify that I'm not mis-interpreting the specs. At this point I've deca-checked, this is what was explicitly stated, the specs are therefore malformed. Future readers could encounter this for myriad reasons however, and the key point is that it's bad design / impossible. 8 pages of poorly formatted instructions rife with typos is only going to confuse people